# Spawning child process from an AWS ECS Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Really simple question, not easily answered looking at the docs: If I deploy a container that starts a Java process, can that process spawn another (also a Java process, but a different one) upon deployment?

The task definition, for other reasons (org restrictions), can have only a single container. Using a standard sidecar is not possible.

Spawning the "sidecar" at startup would be a way around this. Java's ProcessBuilder could do it as long as the java command is accessible (it is).

I just don't know if ECS will allow this.

Comment: You've only tagged this with EC2, but you are talking about Task Definitions. Are you using ECS?

Comment: Yes, ecs. Fixed the tags, thanks.

Comment: You can't spawn an ECS container sidecar from within an ECS container. You can't spawn a sidecar at all, other than by defining it in the task definition.

Comment: This wouldn't be a "sidecar," per se, but just another process in the original container. But it really is the same thing and your comments probably apply.

I figured that was the case, based on the total omission of any such topic in the docs, and the fact that, well, this is what task definitions are for. But had to ask.

Comment: You can launch all the processes you want inside the same container. It works just like any other docker container. ECS isn't going to limit that in any way.

Comment: Ok, great. If bridge networking mode is being used, and the child process binds to a well-known port, the parent should be able to hit it also. I will be able to try this shortly..